# Converting Curl to POST api for java

Tags: java, curl, unirest

I would like to post some data to a rest api.

The [API documentation](https://www.qualys.com/docs/qualys-was-api-user-guide.pdf) (See page 38) asks for the following:

```
curl -u "USERNAME:PASSWORD" -H "Content-type: text/xml" -X "POST"
--data-binary @-
"https://qualysapi.qualys.com/qps/rest/3.0/create/was/webapp/" <
file.xml
Note: “file.xml” contains the request POST data.
Request POST data:
<ServiceRequest>
 <data>
 <WebApp>
 <name><![CDATA[My Web Application]]></name>
 <url><![CDATA[http://mywebapp.com]]></url>
 </WebApp>
 </data>
</ServiceRequest>
```

I have confirmed that the call works on the command line using `curl`.

I then began to write a small app in `Java` and found [UniRest](http://unirest.io/).

Thats where the problem starts. I do not know how to convert the curl request into Unirest.

I have this much so far:

```
Unirest.post("http://apiurl).basicAuth("user","pass").field(name, file).asBinary();
```

the latter half

```
.field(name, file).asBinary();
```

doesnt make sense to me. What is the intent behind giving the file a name. Isn't suppose to retrieve the data from the file?

Furthermore, I would like to avoid writing data to file. How can I create the same `xml` with UniRest.

If not `xml`, could I do the same with `JSON`? The API attached above (appendix C) also accepts `JSON`. However, how can I nest fields with the builder pattern of the `Unirest` api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the UniRest documentation, it looks like you can write any array of bytes to a field in the request. You just have to encode the string into a byte array.

`Unirest.post("http://apiroot")
  .field(name, xmlString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
  .asBinary();`

Alternatively, you can use any `InputStream`,

`Unirest.post("http://apiroot")
  .field(name, new CharSequenceInputStream(xmlString, StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
  .asBinary();`

Usually data is the body of the request though (not as a field). If you do want to send the data as the request body and not a form field, you should use the `body(String body)` method instead of the `field(String name, Object object)` method, for instance:

`String data = "<ServiceRequest>... etc...</ServiceRequest>";
 Unirest.post("http://apiroot")
  .body(xmlString)
  .asBinary();`

Comment: Would it then be `body(xml string)` to match the original `curl` on the command line?

Comment: Yip, I think that will work. Since I cannot run a test case against your server API, I cannot be sure though.

Comment: I will confirm later today and mark as correct if its correct. Do you mind editing your answer with the `body` method and the `xml` data from the above in the mean time?